# Get the rows where they have the same value of the column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two dataframes ch2 and ch3 with an allele column
( I have more ch2 than ch3).
I want to have the rows when both dataframes have the same value.

I have tried this code but every time I get FALSE as result.
THANKS

```
for y in ch2.allele:
    print(y)
    i = ch3.allele
    print(i)
    testtt =(y in i)
    print (testt)
    if (testtt ==True):
        print ("ok")
```

Comment: Just use: `ch2.merge(ch3, left_on='allele', right_on='allele')`

Comment: Thank you for your answer 
But I don't want to join the two tables. I just want to get the rows where they have the same value of the column "allele".

Comment: `I just want to get the rows where they have the same value of the column "allele".` That is exactly what joining two tables is.

Comment: in fact i have two dataframes i can know just when both have the same value of a column but i absolutely do not want to join or concatenate them

Comment: So you want the index of the matching rows in both dataframes, is it?